# What is the "Mean Sq" column of "Residuals" in "anova" of a linear model in R?

Tags: r, anova, lm

Here is anova output from a linear model:

```
> model<-lm(mpg ~ wt + cyl, data = mtcars)
> anova(model)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: mpg
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
wt         1 847.73  847.73  128.60 3.535e-12 ***
cyl        1  87.15   87.15   13.22  0.001064 ** 
Residuals 29 191.17    6.59                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

`Sum Sq` is the sum squared error between mpg and the model prediction.  So, for example, overall residuals:

```
> sum((predict(model, data=mtcars) - mtcars$mpg)^2)
[1] 191.172
```

What exactly is `Mean Sq`?

Comment: It’s the sum of squares divided by thee degrees of freedom. I suggest going through the JBStatistics ANOVA videos: https://youtube.com/results?search_query=jbstatistics+anova.

Comment: Thanks. If you submit this as an answer, I'll accept it. I'd add "191.172/29=6.59 to relate it to the particular output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Mean Sq” is the sum of squares divided by the degrees of freedom. In your example:

```
> 191.17 / 29
[1] 6.592069
```

The mean square for the residuals is related to the variance of the distributions of your groups. In fact, the mean squares of the residuals is an unbiased estimator for that variance!

(At a somewhat higher level, you may see machine learning people talk about mean squared error as a loss function or performance metric, and they might just divide by the sample size instead of the slightly smaller degrees of freedom. That approach does not give an unbiased estimator of the variance of the response distributions, but it results in the same model and can be quicker to calculate. When they say error, they mean the residuals. Technically, this terminology is incorrect, and “residuals” is the proper term, though this abuse of terminology does not seem to cause problems.)

JBStatistics has some good ANOVA videos: https://youtube.com/results?search_query=jbstatistics+anova.